# Contar e agrupar por faixa de dias

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, sum

```
SELECT 
loc.loc_pac as registro, datediff(dd, pac.pac_nasc, getdate()) as 'dias' 
from loc with (nolock), pac with (nolock), str with (nolock) 
where loc.loc_pac <> '' 
and (loc.loc_pac = pac.pac_reg) 
and (loc.loc_str = str.str_cod) 
order by dias
```

Gerando o seguinte resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para agrupar por faixas, tipo:

faixa    |        qtd

0 - 20    |      8

20 - 30     |     2

30 - 40    |      2

...

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo fazer uma tabela de faixas ou uma view, onde você configura os intervalos desejados. Depois é só fazer um `SELECT` com `COUNT` agrupando pela faixa.

Exemplo:

```
create table faixas
(
  faixa varchar(10),
  inicio integer,
  fim integer

);


insert into faixas values ('0-10',0,10);
insert into faixas values ('11-20',11,20);
insert into faixas values ('21-30',21,30);
insert into faixas values ('31-40',31,40);
insert into faixas values ('41-50',41,50);
insert into faixas values ('51-60',51,60);
insert into faixas values ('61-70',61,70);
insert into faixas values ('71-80',71,80);
insert into faixas values ('81-90',81,90);
insert into faixas values ('91-200',91,200);
```

A query:

```
select
    f.faixa,
    count(r.codigo) as qtd
from faixas f
left outer join registros r on r.dias >= f.inicio and r.dias <= f.fim
group by f.faixa;
```

> Resultado:

```
faixa   qtd
0-10    5
11-20   5
21-30   5
31-40   0
41-50   2
51-60   1
61-70   0
71-80   0
81-90   1
91-200  5
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/533450/1)

---

**Update**

Agora que foi informado que está utilizando SQL Server 2008, e não pode criar uma tabela pra isso, você pode usar a [expressão `With`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
with faixas as (

  select '0-10' as faixa, 0 as inicio ,10 as fim
  union
  select '11-20',11,20
  union
  select '21-30',21,30
  union
  select '31-40',31,40
  union
  select '41-50',41,50
  union
  select '51-60',51,60
  union
  select '61-70',61,70
  union
  select '71-80',71,80
  union
  select '81-90',81,90
  union
  select '91-200',91,200
)


select
f.faixa,
count(r.codigo) as qtd
from faixas f
left outer join registros r on r.dias >= f.inicio and r.dias <= f.fim
group by f.faixa;
```

Coloquei no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/88cc99/1)

Comment: Não é possível fazer uma nova tabela pois o banco é de uma empresa responsável pelo sistema, nesse caso preciso montar um select para mostrar o resultado por faixas.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Resposta atualizada